# ASP MVC Data Annotations and database null values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I have a asp mvc 5 project and have created the database using code first and data migrations.

This is my current product POCO class

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please add a product name.")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Features { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public bool? Promotion { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Category")]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Brand")]
    public int BrandId { get; set; }
    public virtual Brand Brand { get; set; }

    public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public string ImageMimeType { get; set; }
}
```

In the database the only values that are not null, is the primary key and the name. I am having a problem with the **Price**, **Category** and **Brand** fields. In the form all 3 are still being *"required"* and the ModelState is not passing with jqueryval.js indicating that this values need to be added.

[image]

As you can see in the image, the form will first show that the price & name values need to be added. Once i add those values and click "create". I am only then asked to add values for the brand and category. As indicated in the image below.

[image]

It seems as if the brand and category and not being validated on the first click for some reason , but besides that these values should not have to be added as they are null values in the database , yet the model still requires that they be added. Just wondering if anyone has any insight to this. Is there maybe a data annotation i can add like

```
[Required(this = false)]
```

To overwrite this.

And also How can i get Brand and category to be validated on the first submit click?

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to make the properties that you want to be optional of a NULLABLE type.

```
public decimal? Price { get; set; }
public int? CategoryId { get; set; }
public int? BrandId { get; set; }
```

This way, the validator will not trigger... and if you think about it for a moment, it makes sense... the default value for an int is 0... but you actually want a NULL in your database.

Comment: sometimes the answer is there but we don't see it

Answer (score 3):

To allow Empty string just add those Annotation

```
[DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings =true)]
```